# Group WordPress posts by category

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

after several unsuccessful searches, I ask my question here.
Indeed, I'm trying to display a list of posts grouped by categories:

**CAT A**

- post1
- post2
- post3

**CAT B**

- post4
- post5
- post6
- post7
  ...

Here is the code I tried.
I can display the categories, but not the posts

```
<?php 
        $terms = get_terms( 'secteur', array(
            'orderby'    => 'count',
            'hide_empty' => 0
        ) );
        
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'client',
                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
              'secteur' => $term->slug
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  
            echo'<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
           

                // Start the Loop
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                $secteur_dactivite = get_field( 'secteur_dactivite' );

                echo '<div class="cat-'.esc_html( $secteur_dactivite->slug ). '"><img src="'.get_field( 'logo' ).'"></div>';

                 endwhile;

            wp_reset_postdata();
 
        } 
    
    ?>
```

Comment: I have implemented this code for WooCommerce product and it seems to be working fine. Have you checked that whether the `get_field()` are having values or not? Try to display title in while loop using `get_the_title()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use tax_query as an WP query attribute, instead of secteur.

Try replacing that with:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'client',
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
  'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'secteur',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term -> slug,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your response.
Unfortunately, this does not change the display. The titles are displayed but not the articles.

```
<h3>CAT1</h3
<h3>CAT2</h3>
<h3>CAT3</h3>
```

If it helps, I can display all the items with the following code :

```
<?php
            $posts = get_posts(array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'client',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            ));
            if($posts)
            {
                echo '<div class="row all-item">';
                foreach($posts as $post)
                {
                    echo '<div"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'"><img src="'.get_field( 'logo' ).'"></a></div>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers.
But nothing has worked for me, and I can’t come up with any solutions.
I think the problem lies in the configuration of my taxonomy.

This is my custom post type configuration (client):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JQtT.jpg

my taxonomy configuration (secteur) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RspoY.jpg

my custom field (secteur_dactivite) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwu3j.jpg

Thanks again for your help